# How to validate a signed cookie against its signature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, websocket

I use `cookie-session` and can decode cookie from headers by using this solution https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/issues/117#issuecomment-452046225:

```
// session=eyJwYXNzcG9ydCI6eyJ1c2VyIjoiNWNiMzdiYzUzZTA2M2YxN2U2M2EzNDdkIn19; session.sig=wCuMz6lIsok00-Dqir3pnblJcAc
const parsedCookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)
const session = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(parsedCookies.session, 'base64').toString('utf8'))
```

If it's correct, I want to allow client to establish WebSocket connection.

Also I have signature which is inside `parsedCookies.sig`.

Value of session is similar to this:

```
{ passport: { user: '5cb37bc53e063f17e63a347d' } }
```

I am seeing this value on server side and it's correct. But, I want to know if this was not modified by user so I want to check `session` against `sig` value. If it's modified, I want to close WebSocket connection.

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you please explain how sig and session are supposed to be related? Your question is not clear enough. Maybe give a clearer example so that I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest use JWT token for token generation.
JWT uses secret key to encode the parameters provided to generate token, usually we provide username, timestamp and user id.

Perform following steps,

1. Store generated token in cookies, also store this to database to validate at each request.
2. Send this cookie with each request, on server side, write authentication middle ware, which will validate this cookie by decoding using Secret Key which was used to generate token. So you can check there if token is modified or not.

For more details, you can visit [JWT](https://jwt.io/)